# Vlookup to the right of a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to vlookup the value to the right of the column.

df1

```
       EW  WE   DA  dd     AA
0  cheese   0  300   T      T
1  dwadaw   3  400  21  31232
```

df 2

```
       AD   FA      BA  DA    daw ddwad
0  dddddd    1     300   T      T     T
1  cheese    1     400  21  31232   NaN
2  chees   dwa  waddcv   3    NaN   NaN
```

Desired:

```
       AD   FA     
0  cheese    1
```

I try:

```
    df3 = df2[['AD', 'FA']].copy()
    df3.FA=np.where(df2.AD.isin(df1.EW),df3.FA,np.nan)
    print (df3)
```

I get output identical to AD and FA in df2

`df3 = df2[df2.AD.isin(df1.EW)]`  gives: `df3 = df2[df2.AD.isin(df1.EW)]   cheese  1.0  300  T   T`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need:

```
df3 = df2[df2.AD.isin(df1.EW)]
df3 = df3[['AD','FA']]
print (df3)
       AD FA
1  cheese  1
```

Comment: For me this gives cheese 1, dwadaw 3, cheese dwa.  I think it's copying AD and FA and  cheese 1 does not appear.

Comment: Maybe using this method but using blank dataframe?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe some problem with data like trailing whitespaces `'  cheese  '`.

Comment: Can you add to question what you get? Because a bit probl;ematic formatting in comments.

Comment: Can do.  It's just copying directly from a csv -> Dataframe.  As I change the csv, it just copies that.  I don't think df3 = df2[df2.AD.isin(df1.EW)] is being read at all.

Comment: If dont read it all there has to be data problem - white spaces, not all same lower/uppercase data. Because it should works.

Comment: The best is check pure data in some text editor for unmatched values.

Comment: That works for me.  Not sure what I did differently, but it is working now.  How strange...  Not complaining.  Hopefully I don't jinx it